# Why can't my Macs recognize my Windows machines by their computer name?

Tags: windows, macos, networking, remote-desktop

I can <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> in Finder on my Macs and connect to my Windows HTPC via `smb://mediaserver`. But if I use the Mac Remote Desktop client and try to connect to that PC via its name `mediaserver`, it can't find it. Why not?

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to install Windows Bonjour services from Apple. This allows your Windows workstations to participate in the mDNS name resolution Mac uses by adding an mDNS Responder service to your workstation.

The Bonjour mDNS Responder service to announce your Windows system on the network should be available in the download from https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/

It also often is one of the components installed by Adobe Creative Suite.

Comment: Can you explain how?

Comment: Back when I was messing with it, Bonjour was automatically installed with Adobe Creative Suite for enabling sharing printers and files between Macs and PCs. I'm not sure if this is the same thing as what Adobe installed -> https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/ You install it and it should start advertising your computer on the network.

Comment: Add that to your answer please :-)

Answer (score 1):

I know when installing iTunes for windows there is an app coming with it called 
"Apple Software Update"

--> http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2305?viewlocale=en_US#

This will list the updates available for apple software on your win PC,
next to the available updates it also gives you the opportunity to install additional apple software on your windows pc, including bonjour.

Or you could take a look at this, this may work as well:
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL999

Description of bonjour:

> Bonjour, also known as zero-configuration networking, enables automatic discovery of computers, devices, and services on IP networks. Bonjour uses industry standard IP protocols to allow devices to automatically discover each other without the need to enter IP addresses or configure DNS servers.